# react-native-firebase: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native-firebase

Almost looks like uploading to storage should work but I end up with this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeFirebase.RNFirebase.storage'
```

I'm not sure what exactly this means—does it think that the native module is undefined or something?

I've tried two ways to get the storage instance:

```
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";

// attempt 1
const storage = firebase.initializeApp(config.firebase[Platform.OS], "myApp").storage();
const storage = firebase.storage();
```

And I put the file into firebase like so:

```
// `blob` is retrieved by calling `fetch(videoUri)`
storage.put(videoUri, {contentType: blob.data.type});
```

After that `put` call occurs, the `UploadTask` is created but rather than uploading that error gets thrown.

The library already has `react-native link` called on it, and other RNFirebase features like authentication are working already.

Any sugggestions? Thanks in advance!